# Display FastFilterFields on top of Grid

Tags: acumatica

I have added FastFilterFields to a grid, and by default displays at the bottom of the grid, and I need to move it to the top. Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.   [image]

I have looked at the Layout Properties of the grid, but have not been able to find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilzing the PXGrid controls `SkinID="PrimaryInquire"` coupled with setting the `FastFilterFields="Field1, Field2, Ect"` would bring the search control from below the grid as can be seen on screen `AP401000`.

***That being said*** It would be more appropriate to modify your design to follow Acumatica methodology.

1. Create a form view page that will represent a single entry in your grid, see page `CS211000` as example.
2. Create a GI that will represent the *list* of entries, make sure the GI utilizes your new screen as the "Entry Screen" option as well as "Replace Entry Screen with this Inquiry in Menu" and "Enable new Record Creation" see GI `CS-ReasonCode` as example.